# How to find all email addresses connected to an email from a phone in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on an app where we need email invitation if the user signs up with his gmail or any other email. So, there we need the user's email contacts that he used to send email. Is there any kind of package in flutter to get all those email contacts for that user?

I have no implementation for the same. Sorry for not providing any code.
Also, I've used contact_service and flutter_contact package to get the phone contacts, but this is not exactly what I want.

Comment: "we need the user's email contacts that he used to send email" - please clarify. If they sign up with Gmail, you want that user's Gmail contacts instead of the contacts on the device? I'm confused as to what data you're trying to get.

Comment: yes, I need that user's gmail contacts. for example - if **abc@gmail.com** is the user and he previously sent 20 emails to other email ids for any reason. I want those 20 email ids for the invitation.

Comment: Have you played around with [gmail.v1](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/gmail.v1/gmail.v1-library.html)? I have not used before, so not sure what's possible with it.

Comment: @daddygames No, I haven't. Lemme look into it. Thanks tho.